# Help making a bootable USB from my Mac

Tags: boot, usb

I have tried many times to make a bootable USB drive to run Ubuntu from my MacBook Air and have failed many times, the instructions that are given are somewhat confusing mostly because I am most definitely not a professional.

Can you give me some detailed instructions? Preferably a how-to video, that would make it a lot more clear.

Answer (score 0):

First, download the Ubuntu image if you haven't done so already.

- Download [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) for Mac and run the software.
- Tick the "Diskimage" radio button and browse for your image-file.
- Choose target drive and press OK.
- Wait for the progress to complete.

Now you just have to boot your Mac from USB and start the installation of Ubuntu.